# PHP, SQL - INSERT INTO SELECET CASE

Tags: php, sql

I have this PHP code connected with form (using nette framework), name of columns are different in every table but `geo` column is in everyone:

```
                $this->masterRepository->query("

                INSERT INTO ".$table." (".$cols.")
                    SELECT ".$cols."
                        CASE
                            WHEN `geo` = '".$values['old_text']."' THEN `geo` = '".$values['new_text']."'
                            ELSE `geo` = '".$values['new_text']."'
                        END
                    FROM ".$table." WHERE `geo` = '".$values['old_text']."';

                ");
```

which generate this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (num_order, geo, url, note)
SELECT num_order, geo, url, note
 CASE
 WHEN `geo` = 'US' THEN `geo` = 'CA'
 ELSE `geo` = 'CA'
 END
FROM some_table 
WHERE `geo` = 'US';
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE
                            WHEN `geo` = 'US' THEN `geo` = 'CA'
```

The goal is to COPY data into the same table but change value of **geo** column before insert.
I know that ELSE value looks stupid but CASE will always end up same because the WHERE selection.

How can I fix this error or should I use different approach? Thanks.

Comment: You're missing a comma before `CASE`.

Comment: You're inserting into 4 column names, but the `SELECT` returns 5 columns. What column should the result of the `CASE` expression be put into?

Comment: What's the point of the `CASE` expression? You're returning the same thing in both cases.

Comment: Another thing: Since you have `WHERE geo = 'US'`, the `WHEN geo = 'US'` case will always be matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error is because you're missing a comma before `CASE`. But there are other problems with the query after fixing that.

You don't need the `CASE` expression at all, since the `WHERE` clause is only selecting those rows. What you want is:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (num_order, url, note, geo)
SELECT num_order, url, note, 'CA'
FROM some_table 
WHERE `geo` = 'US';
```

To do this with your variables, you'll need to remove `geo` from `$cols` so that `SELECT ".$cols` will not include it and you can add `$values["new_text"]` at the end of the `SELECT` list.

```
$cols1 = str_replace('geo,', '', $cols);
$this->masterRepository->query("

    INSERT INTO ".$table." (".$cols1.", geo)
    SELECT ".$cols1.", '".$values['new_text']."'
    FROM ".$table." 
    WHERE `geo` = '".$values['old_text']."';

");
```

Comment: thanks a lot, only correcting $ sign before values['new_text'] in SELECT part

Answer (score 0):

Your alias is wrong `note` should come after `case`
and there is no use of `where` as you are handling the geo values using `CASE`

```
INSERT INTO some_table (num_order, geo, url, note)
SELECT num_order, geo, url, 
CASE
WHEN `geo` = 'US' THEN `geo` = 'CA'
ELSE `geo` = 'CA'
END as note 
FROM some_table
```

Comment: I have a feeling what he actually wants to do is using the CASE as the new value of `geo`. He's copying all the US entries to CA entries.